# Caching Pageable objects (results) in interface that extends CrudRepository

Tags: java, maven, caching, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using spring boot with maven to create a repository that stores results of searched articles and I'm displaying those results through `pagination`, the interface is as follows:

```
public interface HelpArticleSearchRepository extends CrudRepository<HelpArticleSearchResults, Integer> {
    Page<HelpArticleSearchResults> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

My problem is that: I'm getting those results, of searched articles, from a REST API query, and the response is quite slow.

So, I searched online for caching solutions, but the solution I found seems to only work for `methods` that return the same class instance that was used to store the data into the repository. Like:

- [spring-data-examples caching](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/caching)

I was hoping to get a solution that works with `pagination`, but I'm still new to spring boot, so it's a huge challenge.

Please point me in the right direction, for any additional information I'm happy to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Caching and paging are separate issues. Say you have some rest API that serves as your primary data source and is slow. So you want to create some faster reacting cache (no paging issue yet). Of course with your cache come all the relevant issues such as stale data, "hit and miss" and so on and so forth. Say you resolve those issues and now you have a layered data source with a primary slow data source and cache in front of it. Now in your `findAll` method, you rely on Pagination abilities that Spring boot provides you with (regardless of what data source you use). BTW your repository should extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` which extends `CrudRepository`. See reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

Answer (score 1):

You may cache the findAll result [than caching the paginated result] and handle the pagination part from the service layer.

In detail :
Step 1 : For first request - we will cache the findAll result ie for List findAll();
Step 2 : Now pagination will be handled at the serviceLayer and result will be published
Step 3 : From next request onwards you will be refering to the cached result and send the desired set of records from the cache

Based on the type business your application is handling may configure the cache lifetime so that the cache is refreshed at regular intervals. Also remember to set the max size for cache.

Answer (score 1):

I wounldn't post this as an aswer if I wouldn't be limited by char count, as it's not actual answer to your question. It's going to be questioning your needs instead, as you said you're new in this area. Look. Typical approach to caching in early phases of development is: no caching. This this is probably where you are wrong. If you need caching from beginning, I think it's not good, unless you have some exceptional case.

Next. What's your use case? You use caching, because someone is calling findAll to often? That is very weird design, because suppose that your db has millions of records. If you do caching this way, you will just move whole db (theoretically) into memory. If "all data" arent that big, then findAll won't take that much time, and caching is not needed. But if there are a lot of them, nobody probably want them every time, and even if they do and you employ caching somehow, will your whole (500M rows table) fit into memory? Thus as others said, you want pagination. If found it highly improbable, that rest clients will be calling findAll frequently, and for DB tables with lots of records I wouldn't expose this endpoint at all.

Ok, so you have pagination, or relatively small tables. And you want caching of those records. If you use hibernate, maybe you want to use L2 cache, which will do caching of persistence contexts for you correctly (caching isn't that easy, actually).

To wrap up: if possible, change your design not to employ findAll. If not possible use existing solution, like L2 cache. Use your own implementation of db results caching only if you really do not have other option or you really know what you are doing.

Comment: don't know if we're allowed to share links here, but lets try: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache